# DataGrid WPF StackOverFlow Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I am new to WPF and am having a problem with setting up binding to a `DataGrid`. My issue is that I keep getting a `StackOverFlowException` and the debugger breaks on the set statement of the `FirstName` property. I have referred to the follow resources and was unable to solve my problem:

[msdn databinding overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[stackoverflow-with-wpf-calendar-when-using-displaydatestart-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142600/stackoverflow-with-wpf-calendar-when-using-displaydatestart-binding)
[how-to-get-rid-of-stackoverflow-exception-in-datacontext-initializecomponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152222/how-to-get-rid-of-stackoverflow-exception-in-datacontext-initializecomponent)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

My code is:

```
namespace BindingTest
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      ObservableCollection<Person> persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>()
      {
         new Person(){FirstName="john", LastName="smith"},
         new Person(){FirstName="foo", LastName="bar"}
      };

      dataGrid1.ItemsSource = persons;
    }

    class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
      public string FirstName
      {
        get
        {
          return FirstName;
        }

        set
        {
          FirstName = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
      }

      public string LastName
      {
        get
        {
          return LastName;
        }

        set
        {
          LastName = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged("LastName");
        }
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
      {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**`Note about answer`**

For information about the recursion with property settings for anyone else who has the same issue, pleasee see this:

[Why would this simple code cause a stack overflow exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063827/why-would-this-simple-code-cause-a-stack-overflow-exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FirstName = value;` causes recursive call of the property setter. Make something like this:

```
private string firstName;
public string FirstName
{
    get { return firstName;}
    set
    {
        this.firstName = value;
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Pavel! I just wanted to add this link for information about the recursion with property settings for anyone else who has the same issue. [recursive property setters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063827/why-would-this-simple-code-cause-a-stack-overflow-exception)